# Python - finding the longest sequence with findall

Tags: python, regex, findall

```
found = re.findall("g+", "fggfggggfggfg", re.DOTALL)
```

I'd like to find a longest matches for a pattern using findall. I've found some solutions but only for `re.match` or `re.finditer`. Could anybody give me an advice please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`re.DOTALL` does nothing in this case so I've just taken it out for simplicity's sake:

```
>>> import re
>>> max(re.findall("g+", "fggfggggfggfg"), key=len)
'gggg'
```

If you need all of them in order of length:

```
>>> sorted(re.findall("g+", "fggfggggfggfg"), key=len, reverse=True)
['gggg', 'gg', 'gg', 'g']
```

Comment: +1, and I would also point out that the `re.DOTALL` flag isn't doing anything useful.

Comment: @2rec I assumed that was the case